# Bind DataSource to new DevExpress Report Designer?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to set my `DataSource` as the default when a user clicks <kbd>New Report</kbd>, or for any new report, in the DevExpress User Data Report Designer.

Right now, the Blank Report I have load on `Form_Load` has my `DataSources` just fine, but anytime I hit <kbd>New Report</kbd>, they're gone.

I've googled and followed the docs, but they all seem to be geared towards opening a specific report (as above).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**0. ICommandHandler interface**

You need to handle the `ReportCommand.NewReport` command by implementing the [`ICommandHandler`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/clsDevExpressXtraReportsUserDesignerICommandHandlertopic) interface. You must pass an object that implementing this interface to the [`XRDesignMdiController.AddCommandHandler`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUserDesignerXRDesignMdiController_AddCommandHandlertopic.aspx) method. You can get `XRDesignMdiController` object from `ReportDesignTool.DesignForm.DesignMdiController` property or from `ReportDesignTool.DesignRibbonForm.DesignMdiController` property according to what type of form you want to use.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub ShowReportDesigner()
    Dim tool As New ReportDesignTool(CreateReport)
    Dim controller = tool.DesignRibbonForm.DesignMdiController

    Dim handler As New NewCommandHandler(controller, AddressOf CreateReport)

    controller.AddCommandHandler(handler)

    tool.ShowRibbonDesigner()
End Sub

Private Function CreateReport() As XtraReport

    Dim report As New XtraReport
    report.DataSource = YourDataSourceObjectHere

    Return report

End Function

Public Class NewCommandHandler
    Implements ICommandHandler

    Private ReadOnly _controller As XRDesignMdiController
    Private ReadOnly _createReport As Func(Of XtraReport)

    Public Sub New(controller As XRDesignMdiController, createReport As Func(Of XtraReport))
        _controller = controller
        _createReport = createReport
    End Sub

    Public Function CanHandleCommand(command As ReportCommand, ByRef useNextHandler As Boolean) As Boolean Implements ICommandHandler.CanHandleCommand
        useNextHandler = command <> ReportCommand.NewReport
        Return Not useNextHandler
    End Function

    Public Sub HandleCommand(command As ReportCommand, args() As Object) Implements ICommandHandler.HandleCommand
        _controller.OpenReport(_createReport())
    End Sub
End Class
```

**1. DesignPanelLoaded event**

The another way is to subscribe to [`XRDesignMdiController.DesignPanelLoaded`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUserDesignerXRDesignMdiController_DesignPanelLoadedtopic) event. In this event you can check where the `DataSource` of report in loaded panel is empty and set it to your data source.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub ShowReportDesigner()
    Dim report As New XtraReport
    report.DataSource = YourDataSourceObjectHere

    Dim tool As New ReportDesignTool(New XtraReport)
    Dim controller = tool.DesignRibbonForm.DesignMdiController

    AddHandler controller.DesignPanelLoaded, AddressOf mdiController_DesignPanelLoaded

    tool.ShowRibbonDesigner()
End Sub

Private Sub mdiController_DesignPanelLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DesignerLoadedEventArgs)
    Dim panel = DirectCast(sender, XRDesignPanel)
    Dim report = panel.Report

    If IsNothing(report.DataSource) Then
        report.DataSource = YourDataSourceObjectHere
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: nemoBu4, the first method works perfectly, thank you! But the same problem exists - the Data fields disappear when I click New Report. My other questions would be, how would I change the title of the Report Designer and the New Report name (both are XtraReport). Thanks!

Comment: @Chris I have no idea why your data fields disappear. Can you show your code? Your other questions you can ask by using the «Ask question» button. Please, don't use comments for asking new questions.